# IBM Content Navigator ICN Plugin returns an error when configured but works fine

Tags: plugins, ibm-content-navigator

I am using ICN 3.0.3 IF7.  I have a custom plugin that writes the following error to the console when I initially configure it into ICN.

The plugin itself works fine once configured.

```
Uncaught TypeError: cls is not a constructor
    at Object.eval (ecm/widget/layout/AdminPane.js:9845)
    at dojo.js.jgz:22442
    at runFactory (dojo.js.jgz:611)
    at execModule (dojo.js.jgz:691)
    at dojo.js.jgz:397
    at guardCheckComplete (dojo.js.jgz:699)
    at contextRequire (dojo.js.jgz:396)
    at req (dojo.js.jgz:32)
    at Object._displayPluginConfig (ecm/widget/layout/AdminPane.js:9844)
    at Object._pluginRequestCompleted (ecm/widget/layout/AdminPane.js:9759)
```

In addition, once it is configured, I cannot get the details on it like I can for the included AFP Viewer plugin:

```
Name:               AFP Viewer
Version:            2.0.3.5
Repository types:   None
Actions:            None
Open Actions:       None
Viewers:            AFP Viewer
Features:           None
Layouts:            None
```

It seems like something is wrong with the plugin structure that doesn't affect its ability to run.  I am worried because I just don't like seeing errors.  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error it seems like the module you specified in the plugin.java#getConfigurationDijitClass is either failing to instantiate, or isn't specified at all.

If you have a configuration dijit class configured, then ensure it's actually a widget and that it's constructor and postCreate method (if provided) don't throw an error :).

If you don't have one configured, set it to null to prevent instantiation